# Linear interpolation in loops

Tags: r, loops, interpolation

I have two files. One file has five observations of “Flux” across a three treatment experiment (treatments=A, B, C). In these three treatments temperatures have been manipulated. The observations of Flux are taken at five points in a 24 hr period. The second file (Temp) contains the temperatures for the three treatments across the 24 hour period.

I would like to use linear interpolation to predict what the Flux values will be at every hour during the 24 hour period. Note that the interpolation equations will be slightly different between the three treatments.

Can this be done in a loop so that the values of flux are estimated for each hour in the Temp.csv file? Then have the values integrated (summed) across the 24 hour period?

The files are available on dropbox here: [Temp Data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sl5dq1javbd07md/fg4v6Y6FCw)

This shows: the different slopes of the best fit linear relationships between flux and temperature across the three treatments:

```
#subset data in flux by treatment
fluxA<-flux[which(flux$Treatment=='A'),]
fluxB<-flux[which(flux$Treatment=='B'),]
fluxC<-flux[which(flux$Treatment=='C'),]

#Regression of Flux~Temperature
modelA<-lm (Flux~Temperature, data=fluxA)
summary (modelA)

modelB<-lm (Flux~Temperature, data=fluxB)
summary (modelB)

modelC<-lm (Flux~Temperature, data=fluxC)
summary (modelC)

#plot the regressions
plot (Flux~Temperature, data=fluxA,pch=16, xlim=c(0,28), ylim=c(0,20))
abline(modelA)

points(Flux~Temperature, data=fluxB,pch=16, col="orange")
abline(modelB, col="orange")

points(Flux~Temperature, data=fluxC,pch=16, col="red")
abline(modelC, col="red")
```

Comment: You don't need a loop. However, from your question it is not clear what you want to do. It doesn't seem like you want to interpolate (there are no time values in the flux file). Rather it seems like you want to do (linear?) regressions `flux ~ temp` and than predict for your temp data. Please clarify.

Comment: That is correct I do want to predict flux using temperature. I only think that this has to happen in a loop because the linear regression coefficients are different for the three treatments. @Roland

Comment: Also, please note that this is only a small subset of a much MUCH larger dataset but if this works then processing the larger dataset should work pretty much the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
caldat <- read.csv(text="Treatment,Temperature,Flux
A,18.64,7.75
A,16.02,8.49
A,17.41,9.24
A,21.06,4.42
A,22.8,5.61
B,19.73,5.7
B,17.45,8.37
B,19.2,5.27
B,20.97,3.37
B,27.6,2.26
C,23.79,9.91
C,15.89,15.8
C,21.93,10.28
C,24.79,6.33
C,26.64,6.64
")

plot(Flux~Temperature, data=caldat, col=Treatment)
mod <- lm(Flux~Temperature*Treatment, data=caldat)
summary(mod)
points(rep(seq(16,28, length.out=1e3),3), 
       predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(Temperature=rep(seq(16,28, length.out=1e3),3),
                                       Treatment=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=1e3))),
       pch=".", col=rep(1:3, each=1e3))
```

[image]

You'll need to consider carefully if this is an appropriate and "good" model. Use standard regression diagnostics.

```
preddata <- read.csv(text="Time,A,B,C
100,17.8,21.64,23.04
200,17.5,21.3,22.7
300,17.23,21,22.39
400,16.92,20.67,22.08
500,16.47,20.3,21.74
600,15.78,19.75,21.24
700,15.19,19.14,20.63
800,14.58,18.47,20
900,14.22,17.99,19.49
1000,13.77,17.55,19.08
1100,13.39,17.02,18.62
1200,13.34,16.76,18.26
1300,13.17,16.62,18.05
1400,13.24,16.58,17.91
1500,13.31,16.63,17.86
1600,13.26,16.61,17.81
1700,13.12,16.57,17.75
1800,12.9,16.45,17.65
1900,12.74,16.32,17.54
2000,12.57,16.2,17.42
2100,12.36,16.04,17.28
2200,12.1,15.83,17.1
2300,11.79,15.57,16.88
2400,11.53,15.3,16.64
")

library(reshape2)
preddata <- melt(preddata, id="Time",
                 variable.name="Treatment", value.name="Temperature")
preddata$Flux <- predict(mod, newdata=preddata)

plot(Flux~Time, data=preddata, col=Treatment)
```

[image]

Sum the fluxes:

```
aggregate(Flux ~ Treatment, data=preddata, FUN=sum)
#  Treatment     Flux
#1         A 247.5572
#2         B 159.6803
#3         C 309.6186
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Does this prediction treat each of the experimental treatments independently? such that the regressed relationships between temp and flux are different for each treatment or is it just one regression to estimate flux all treatments?

Comment: The model estimates independent intercepts and slopes for each treatment. You should study tutorials on linear regression if you don't see this.